# Import orders on Magento

Tags: mysql, magento, csv, magento-1.7

I've recently upgraded my Magento store from 1.4.2 to 1.7.

I did this upgrade on a local machine as the online store was still running. As an effect, I had customers making orders on the online database while I was upgrading the local database to 1.7.

Now I need to merge the orders from both databases so I don't lose any order in the backoffice.

I've looked into some extensions but they're all paid.

How can I achieve this without having to pay for an extension I'll only use once?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with sql I think.

The order data can be found in tables prefixed with 'sales_flat'. What you need is to merge the orders from the old database into the new database that don't exist in the new database.

Problem might be that new orders in the new database might have the same ids as the orders from the old database.

I'd say do something like (as a sketch):

**-> Obtain the orders you want from sales_flat_order table.** You need to join their data with the data from the other sales_flat tables, like sales_flat_payment for payment data and sales_flat_item for item data. But this can be done at a later point because they can cause key constraint errors if not imported in the correct order.
**-> Determine valid entity_ids and increment_ids for the orders, so that they do not overlap with orders in the new database**
**-> Import the orders in the new database (sql import)** After this has been done for sales_flat_order you can do this for the other sales_flat tables.

Now they should be imported. Be wary though that any order information that is stored in other modules is not available (mage_report module for example stores some statistics information) but I think the important information is merged this way.

Comment: i've tried both this approach as well as one where i imported all the 'sales_' tables cleanly (overwrote the current ones) and have come into many issues. most prominent ones: subtotal calculation totally off, tax calculation problems, order totals differ with that of their invoice and many more. have not found a solution yet.